# How can I undo Gmail's "always display images" setting for multiple senders at once?

Tags: gmail

I have the **Images** option in [Gmail Settings > General](https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general) set to **"Ask before displaying external images"**.

Over many years I have enabled the option to **"Always display images from <sender-address>"** many times.

With a better understanding of how images can be used to track my behaviour, I'd like to undo my previous choices.

This related Web Apps question and its answers, [Undo "Always display images from this sender"](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/103469/undo-always-display-images-from-this-sender) is about undoing the setting for a single sender, but I'm trying to do it for all senders and start fresh.

Is there a way to reset this setting for all senders?

Comment: Does [using the Android app's "Clear picture approvals"](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/47886/363058) work?

Comment: Nice one Laurel!  You should write that  workaround up as an answer.  I don't see another option and wasn't aware of that feature in the Android App.

Comment: I don't have an android phone. Was hoping for a web interface solution.

Comment: @cfm see if the IOS app has similar functionality then.